# Johnson's Algorithm graph explanation

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Can anybody explain the Johnson's Algorithm for the graph below? 
I am really confused about how the algorithm works. I know that it is a combination of the `Bellman Ford` and `Dijkstra's`.

But I am unable to find a good graph explanation, that explains the solution step by step.

Here is the graph.
[image: Graph]

Note regarding distances: from f to b is -5 (not 5); g to e is -3 (not 3); b to d is -5 (not 5)

Thank you very much. I know that I have to change the weights first, but I am not really sure as to how to change the weights.

**Question:** I want to find the shortest path from b to c.

Comment: As I understand it, Johnson's has 3 steps: 1) introduce a new node and compute the shortest paths from the new node to all old nodes, 2) change the weights, 3) find the shortest path from b to c. Is step 2) the one you're having trouble with?

Comment: @Beta yes. I am having trouble w/ change the weights. I am really confused about how to change it, although i know the formula is w'(u,v) = w(u,v) +h(u)- h(v). But when i read the Cormen's Intro to Algorithm chapter about Johnson's algorithm example, I really could not figure out by myself. I hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've already done, we introduce a new node, call it **z**, with weight-0 connections to all other nodes. We work out the shortest paths from **z** to each other path and get:

```
h(a) =   0
h(b) =  -5
h(c) =   0
h(d) = -10
h(e) =  -4
h(f) =   0
h(g) =  -1
```

Then we recalculate the weights of the edges:

```
w'(a,d) = w(a,d) + h(a) - h(d) = 11 +    0  - (-10) = 21
w'(b,a) = w(b,a) + h(b) - h(a) =  7 +  (-5) -    0  =  2
w'(b,d) = w(b,d) + h(b) - h(d) = -5 +  (-5) - (-10) =  0
w'(c,a) = w(c,a) + h(c) - h(a) = 17 +    0  -    0  = 17
w'(c,b) = w(c,b) + h(a) - h(b) =  3 +    0  -  (-5) =  8
w'(d,f) = w(d,f) + h(d) - h(f) = 12 + (-10) -    0  =  2
...
```

Then use Dijkstra to find the shortest pat hfrom **a** to **b**. Does that cover it?

Comment: How did you get the h(a) to h(g)?

Comment: @KellyAnn: I thought you had that part. The texts say to use the [Bellman-Ford algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Algorithm) (which I don't really know). I did it with pencil and paper, but I think I may have been using an equivalent of the Bellman-Ford algorithm without knowing it. I started with all zeroes, then looked for places open to improvement.

Comment: Thank you! I think my confused is more about Bellman-ford. I am going to look over that wiki page. Thank you for the whole explanation about Johnson's. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: Thx for this. But do you have any idea of how to get the intuition of adding such a node. Why are the weight of minimal path the value of h() ? I can verify this works but where does that idea come from ?

Comment: I found the answer in this video : https://class.coursera.org/algo2-002/lecture/157. Correctness of the algorithm is explained at 9:00. All comes from the inequality W(i,j)+f(i)>f(j) which recalls the general formula of f being a smaller cost function.